# Can you jump a scanner to a location in file or scan backwards?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have a very large text file and I need to gather data from somewhere near the end.  Maybe Scanner isn't the best way to do this but it would be very wasteful to start at the top and grab 6000 lines before getting to the part of the file I am interested in.  Is there a way to either tell Scanner to jump to say 7/8ths down the document or start from the bottom and scan upwards grabbing line by line?

Thanks

Comment: 6000 lines doesn't sound like much.  Have you tried it? Does this run often enough to make it worth complicating everything?

Comment: 6000 is just my watered down text file.  I am concerned about much much larger files in the field.  I am also putting a large focus on the programs responsiveness and I don't want to hold up the system with any processing it doesn't really need to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The underlying input source for a `java.util.Scanner` is a [`java.lang.Readable`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Readable.html). Beyond the `Scanner(File)` constructor, a `Scanner` neither knows nor cares of the fact that it's scanning a file.

Also, since it's regex based on `java.util.regex.*`, there's no way it can scan backward.

To accomplish what you want to do, it's best to do it at the input source level, e.g. by using [`InputStream.skip`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#skip%28long%29) of the source before passing it to the constructor of `Scanner`.

---

#### On `Scanner.skip`

`Scanner` itself does have a [`skip`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#skip%28java.util.regex.Pattern%29), and a pattern like `"(?s).{10}"` would skip 10 characters (in `(?s)` single-line/[`Pattern.DOTALL`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL) mode), but this is perhaps a rather roundabout way of doing it.

Here's an example of using `skip` to skip a given number of lines.

```
    String text =
        "Line1 blah blah\n" +
        "Line2 more blah blah\n" +
        "Line3 let's try something new \r\n" +
        "Line4 meh\n" + 
        "Line5 bleh\n" + 
        "Line6 bloop\n";
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(text).skip("(?:.*\\r?\\n|\\r){4}");
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
    }
```

This prints ([as seen on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/rhQre)):

```
Line5 bleh
Line6 bloop
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I guess I missed the skip function in the Scanner API listing.  I think I will take advantage of the InputStream.skip though.

Comment: @Mike: yes, Mark Peters is spot on. If you know how many bytes you want to skip, skip at the `InputStream` level. If you don't, e.g. you want to skip some number of lines, and the input is dynamic enough that you can't preprocess it to create an index out of it, then just `Scanner.skip`. Needless to say, this method skips _by matching_ the input, so it actually does quite an amount of work.

Comment: The `skip` part gives me `java.lang.StackOverflowError` when I try to put an argument instead of the `4` in a static method

Answer (score 2):

`Scanner` wraps an `InputStream`, you can use the stream's `skip(long)`  method to skip the lines you don't want and then start scanning.

Read more in the `InputStream` [javadoc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#skip%28long%29)

Comment: The obvious difficulty there is that `skip` doesn't skip *lines*, it skips *bytes*, and there's no way to tell how many bytes are in each line without reading them.  But it's a good way to skip some data.

Comment: @Mark Peters: Great comment - I did not take that into consideration.

Comment: This is still very usable for me.  Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably use [RandomAccessFile](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) instead.

Comment: RandomAccessFile is no good if the content needs to be read sequentially, though.