# I'm struggling iterating backwards over input to create a Normal Polish Notation Calculator

Tags: java, stack, calculator

I'm trying to make a Normal (Prefix) Polish Notation Calculator in Java. I can't seem to make Java read the input backwards and input each integer into a stack, then perform the calculation on them after popping.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;
public class add
{
    static boolean inputIsOperator(String next) {
        return (next.equals("+") || next.equals("-") || next.equals("x"));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    //String trimmedInput[] = args;
    //trimmedInput=args.split("\\s+");

    Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();
    String size = scanner.next();
    String next = size;
    //System.out.println(size.length());

    for (int i = next.length()-1; i > -1; i--) {

        while (!next.equals("")) {
            //next = scanner.next();
            System.out.println(next);

            if (!(inputIsOperator(next))) {
                try {
                    String number = String.valueOf(next);
                    stack.push(number);
                } catch (NumberFormatException c) {
                    System.out.println("Try a proper NPN equation");
                }
            }
            else if (inputIsOperator(next)) {

                //Integer newinput = Integer.parseInt(input);
                //System.out.println(stack.size());

                if (stack.size() > 1) {
                    if (next.equals("x")) {
                        int op1 = Integer.parseInt(stack.pop());
                        int op2 = Integer.parseInt(stack.pop());
                        stack.push(String.valueOf((op1 * op2))); {
                    } else if (next.equals("-")) {
                        int op1 = Integer.parseInt(stack.pop());
                        int op2 = Integer.parseInt(stack.pop());
                        stack.push(String.valueOf((op1 - op2)));
                    } else if (next.equals("+")) {
                        int op1 = Integer.parseInt(stack.pop());
                        int op2 = Integer.parseInt(stack.pop());
                        stack.push(String.valueOf((op1 + op2)));
                    }
                }
            }
            next = scanner.next(); //works here but gives nosuchelementexception
        }

    }
    System.out.println(stack.pop());
}
}
```

Expecting, when inputting for example + - 10 1 2 for it to perform 10-1 then + 2, giving an output of 11.

I also have another version which seems to work but only Polish Notation, so e.g. '2 5 8  + -' gives an output of 11 whereas '+ - 2 5 8' gives an output of 8:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;
public class add2
{
// instance variables - replace the example below with your own
private String operator;
public String main[];
public static boolean inputIsOperator(String next) {
    return (next.equals("+") || next.equals("-") || next.equals("x"));
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    //String trimmedInput[] = args;
    //trimmedInput=args.split("\\s+");

    Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();
    //String size = scanner.next();
    String next;
    //System.out.println(size.length());

    //for (int i = size.length(); i > -1; i--) {

        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            next = scanner.next();
            //System.out.println(next);

            if (!(inputIsOperator(next))) {
                try {
                    String number = String.valueOf(next);
                    stack.push(number);
                } catch (NumberFormatException c) {
                    System.out.println("Try a proper NPN equation");
                }
            }
            else if (inputIsOperator(next)) {

                //Integer newinput = Integer.parseInt(input);
                //System.out.println(stack.size());

                if (stack.size() > 1) {
                    if (next.equals("x")) {
                        int op1 = Integer.parseInt(stack.pop());
                        int op2 = Integer.parseInt(stack.pop());
                        stack.push(String.valueOf((op1 * op2))); {
                    } else if (next.equals("-")) {
                        int op1 = Integer.parseInt(stack.pop());
                        int op2 = Integer.parseInt(stack.pop());
                        stack.push(String.valueOf((op2 - op1)));
                    } else if (next.equals("+")) {
                        int op1 = Integer.parseInt(stack.pop());
                        int op2 = Integer.parseInt(stack.pop());
                        stack.push(String.valueOf((op1 + op2)));
                    }
                }
             }
        }
    //}
    System.out.println(stack.pop());
}
}
```

Comment: You might find it easier to debug your code if you changed the type of your stack to `Stack<Integer>` and parse the values before pushing them.

Comment: What happens when you step through your code in your debugger?

Comment: @dave I am not sure how to debug at this stage... I'm relatively new to this and we've kinda been thrust into an assignment. Can I do this using InjelliJ IDEA?

Comment: Yes, IntelliJ has a debugger. Rather than using `Run` to execute your program, use `Debug` (which has a beetle icon). Double-click to the left of a line of code to add a breakpoint. Your program should stop at the breakpoint and you can inspect values. Then step through your code line-by-line.

Comment: Why do you think you need to read the input backwards?

Comment: @Jim Mischel I need to add the numbers from right to left into the stack, then when it gets to an operator, perform the calculations on the last stacked numbers

Comment: @JimMischel, I'm trying to make my calculator read the input backwards to it will read it as + - 2 5 8, adding 8 into the stack first, then 5 and finally 2. As it reaches the - it should then take (pop) 2 from the stack, minus the next item in the stack, 5 (giving us 2-5) and placing the value back into the stack (-3). It should then continue, find the + and then do -3+8, store the value back in the stack and finally output it via system.out.println.

Comment: @dave I need to add a configuration so I can debug and I'm not sure what I should be using, could you advise?

Comment: @ryan I think if you right-click on your class, you find _Run_ and _Debug_ in the menu. Selecting either one should execute your program (with or without debug) and create a _Run Configuration_ at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see what you're trying to do now. Let's first take a look at your code for evaluating postfix expressions (the second code block).

Your subtraction is backwards. You have:

```
else if (next.equals("-")) {
    stack.push(String.valueOf((Integer.parseInt(stack.pop())) - (Integer.parseInt(stack.pop()))));
```

Consider the postfix expression `2 1 -`. This corresponds to the infix expression `2 - 1`. So when you're evaluating the postfix, you push 2 and 1, and then see the operator. Your code pops 1, and pops 2, and executes `1 - 2`. But it was supposed to execute `2 - 1`.

You need to reverse the order of operands in your subtraction. That is:

```
op1 = stack.pop();
op2 = stack.pop();
stack.push(op2 - op1);
```

You make the same mistake in your code that reads prefix expressions in reverse order.

Let's take the prefix expression `+ - 10 1 2` and convert it to postfix.

```
input     action     operand stack
  2        push        2
  1        push        1, 2
 10        push        10, 1, 2
  -        evaluate    9
  +        evaluate    11
```

But your code will do `1-10` to get `-9`.

Note also that the prefix expression `+ - 2 5 8` corresponds to the infix expression `2-5+8`. The postfix expression `2 5 8 + -` corresponds to the infix expression `2-(5+8)`.

The postfix expression that corresponds to `+ - 2 5 8` is `2 5 - 8 +`.

### Reading backwards

I'm not really a Java programmer, so somebody can correct me if I'm wrong. But from what I've read (see, for example, [Can you jump a scanner to a location in file or scan backwards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3064373/can-you-jump-a-scanner-to-a-location-in-file-or-scan-backwards)), you can't really use `Scanner` to read backwards.

What I would suggest is that you read the line from the start, and push each token onto a stack. Then read from the stack in your loop. Something like:

```
Stack<string> inputStack = new Stack<string>();
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
while (sc.hasNext()) {
    inputStack.push(sc.next());
}
```

The tokens are now on the `inputStack` in reverse order. You can read them backwards by popping them from the stack.

```
while (!inputStack.empty()) {
    String next = inputStack.pop();
    System.out.println(next);  // just to make sure it's reading correctly
    if (!isOperator(next)) {
       ...
    }
    // ... rest of your code goes here
}
```

As I said, I'm not really a Java programmer and I don't have a Java dev environment set up here, so I can't guarantee that'll work, but it looks like it should.

Comment: Thank you for that @JimMischel! That's helped. Now my only problem is basically, using the first block of code, it doesn't seem to be reading the input backwards. It only adds the final number in the input to the stack, and outputs it. In this case, that's 8. It also sometimes gives the error 'EmptyStackException', depending on where I put `next=scanner.next();`.